# collision on sprites

Tags: collision-detection, coronasdk

how can i add collision effects on my sprites...
sir i'm using sprite for my object.and it is working fine but it didnt collide with any other object added in physics.i didnt find anything related that ,can i have to add my sprite in physics?is it possible?

Comment: Really, that's it? And you expect someone will be able to *answer* this?

Comment: sir i'm using sprite for my object.and it is working fine but it didnt collide with any other object added in physics.i didnt find anything related that ,can i have to add my sprite in physics?is it possible?

Comment: you should check out gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the physics on a `display.newCircle()`and make that react how you want your character to, and later set its `alpha` to 0.

Then make your sprites `x` and `y` equal to the displays `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sprite is something you have gotten with display.newSprite() or display.newImage() you can just add the sprito to physics as for any other displayObject you got.

Making a newCircle() as the answer above suggests is unnecessary.